# Display UIViewController from bottom with an animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `UIViewController` created in `StoryBoard`. Now, i want to display it so it fills in **ONLY 70%** of the screen (Displays partially with an animation- appearing from bottom to top). How can i do this ?

My code:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    myViewController.title=@"title";
[myViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height*0.7)];
[self myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What i see is a black view covering the entire screen. How to resolve it.

Note: I do not want to use `UIView`.

Comment: "I do not want to use UIView" - a view is a view and a view controller is managing a view; they are not interchangeable concepts. What you *probably* want is a view that covers 70% of your current view and is *managed* by a view controller.

Comment: You can't do it with a viewcontroller. Use a `UIView`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a child view controller.  You will have to add it as a subview with frame off the screen and animate it up on your own.

Check documentation, there's a few things you need to do for child view controllers.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Answer (score 0):

As Augie says in his answer, what you need to do is set up a child view controller and animate it onto the screen.

The easiest way to do this is to create a container view in your parent view controller ("Search on "container view in the "object library" in Interface Builder and drag a container view onto your parent view controller.) Then control-drag from that container view to another scene in your storyboard. That lets you set up an "embed segue" that loads the child view into the container view when the parent VC is loaded. It's misleading to call it a segue, since it's a link that loads the child VC inside the parent when the parent loads, not a transition to another VC, but Apple calls it an embed segue. Your prepareForSegue method fires when the parent loads and the imbed segue is invoked to load the child VC, so it does act more-or-less like a segue.